# Simple memo game project

Tags: game, react.js, jsx, redux

I created my first React app with Redux and this a simple memo game with possibility to select difficulty level. I am new in React world, so it would be great if you review my project :)

### Project structure:

```html
src
    │   App.js
    │   App.scss
    │   App.test.js
    │   cards-data.js
    │   index.js
    │   index.scss
    │   reportWebVitals.js
    │   setupTests.js
    │
    ├───components
    │   ├───button
    │   │       button.component.jsx
    │   │       button.styles.scss
    │   │
    │   ├───cards-directory
    │   │       cards-directory.component.jsx
    │   │       cards-directory.styles.scss
    │   │
    │   ├───counter
    │   │       counter.component.jsx
    │   │       counter.styles.scss
    │   │
    │   └───single-card
    │           single-card.component.jsx
    │           single-card.styles.scss
    │
    ├───routes
    │   ├───game-area
    │   │       game-area.component.jsx
    │   │       game-area.component.styles.scss
    │   │
    │   └───menu
    │           menu.component.jsx
    │           menu.styles.scss
    │
    └───store
        │   reducer.utils.js
        │   root-reducer.js
        │   store.js
        │
        ├───cards
        │       cards.action.js
        │       cards.reducer.js
        │       cards.selector.js
        │       cards.types.js
        │
        ├───counter
        │       counter.action.js
        │       counter.reducer.js
        │       counter.selector.js
        │       counter.types.js
        │
        └───game-difficulty
                game-difficulty.action.js
                game-difficulty.reducer.js
                game-difficulty.selector.js
                game-difficulty.types.js
```

### App.js

```js
import Menu from './routes/menu/menu.component';
import GameArea from './routes/game-area/game-area.component';

import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Menu />}></Route>
        <Route path="/game-area" element={<GameArea />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### App.scss

```css
.app-container {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 12vh 0;
}
```

### cards-data.js

```js
export const CARDS_DATA = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'empty_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/Jsznnmg/empty-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'buffalo_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/4Zyt8yR/buffalo-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'desert_fennec_fox_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/G7bPZKD/desert-fennec-fox-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'duck_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/Y05XH1K/duck-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'kangaroo_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/KGPXL5W/kangaroo-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'leopard_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/jGYcQ1v/leopard-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'lion_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/x1Vqykv/lion-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'raccoon_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/7v0dKRK/raccoon-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: 'red_bear_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/qgjMjNJ/red-bear-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        name: 'tiger_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/NTnjGSn/tiger-card.png'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'zebra_card',
        imagePath: 'https://i.ibb.co/jk1GDHg/zebra-card.png'
    }
];
```

### index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor } from './store/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bit.ly/CRA-vitals
reportWebVitals();
```

### index.scss

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #F0D7D1;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

### button.component.jsx

```js
import './button.styles.scss';

export const BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES = {
    start: 'start',
    restart: 'restart',
    difficultyEasy: 'difficulty-easy',
    difficultyMedium: 'difficulty-medium',
    difficultyHard: 'difficulty-hard',
};

const Button = ({ children, buttonType, ...otherProps }) => {
    return (
        <button className={`button-container ${buttonType}`} {...otherProps}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

### button.styles.scss

```css
.button-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #4a586e;
}

.start {
  background-color: #feac92;
  border: 3px dashed #4a586e;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.difficulty-easy,
.difficulty-medium,
.difficulty-hard {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 130px;
}

.difficulty-easy {
  background-color: #d4f794;
  border: 3px dashed #8ea663;
}

.difficulty-medium {
  background-color: #f3f59a;
  border: 3px dashed #979957;
}

.difficulty-hard {
  background-color: #f5bd9a;
  border: 3px dashed #995f3a;
}

.difficulty-easy:focus {
  background-color: #b3d07e;
}

.difficulty-medium:focus {
  background-color: #c1c27a;
}

.difficulty-hard:focus {
  background-color: #ca9c80;
}

.restart {
  background-color: #fef0ef;
  border: 2px solid #ae5f5f;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  color: #ae5f5f;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

### cards-directory.component.jsx

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
    selectCards,
    selectEmptyImagePath,
} from '../../store/cards/cards.selector';
import { selectCounterValue } from '../../store/counter/counter.selector';
import {
    setCurrentImagePath,
    setIsCardDisabled,
    setIsRotationDisabled,
} from '../../store/cards/cards.action';
import { setCounterValue } from '../../store/counter/counter.action';
import SingleCard from '../single-card/single-card.component';
import './cards-directory.styles.scss';

const CardsDirectory = ({ cardType }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const cards = useSelector(selectCards);
    const counterValue = useSelector(selectCounterValue);
    const emptyImagePath = useSelector(selectEmptyImagePath);
    const cardsToCompare = cards.filter(
        (card) => card.currentImagePath === card.imagePath && !card.isCardDisabled
    );
    const isRotationDisabled = true;

    const toggleEmptyImagePath = (cardsToSetEmptyImagePath) =>
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(
                setCurrentImagePath(cards, cardsToSetEmptyImagePath, emptyImagePath)
            );
        }, 1000);

    const toggleIsCardDisabled = (cardsToDisable) =>
        dispatch(setIsCardDisabled(cards, cardsToDisable));

    const toggleCounterValue = () => {
        const increasedCounterValue = counterValue + 1;
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(setCounterValue(increasedCounterValue));
        }, 1000);
    };

    const toggleIsRotationDisabled = () =>
        dispatch(setIsRotationDisabled(isRotationDisabled));

    const toggleIsRotationEnabled = () => setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(setIsRotationDisabled(!isRotationDisabled));
    }, 1000);

    const compareCards = () => {
        cardsToCompare.reduce((prevCard, currentCard) =>
            prevCard.imagePath !== currentCard.imagePath
                ? toggleEmptyImagePath(cardsToCompare)
                : toggleIsCardDisabled(cardsToCompare)
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cardsToCompare.length < 2) return;

        toggleIsRotationDisabled();
        compareCards();
        toggleIsRotationEnabled();
        toggleCounterValue();
    });

    return (
        <div className={`cards-directory-container ${cardType}`}>
            {cards.map((card) => (
                <SingleCard key={card.id} card={card} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardsDirectory;
```

### cards-directory.styles.scss

```css
.cards-directory-container {
  background-color: #fef0ef;
  border: 5px solid #fef0ef;
  border-radius: 4%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.easy {
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}

.medium {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.hard {
  width: 620px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

### counter.component.jsx

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectCounterValue } from '../../store/counter/counter.selector';
import './counter.styles.scss';

const Counter = () => {
    const currentCounterValue = useSelector(selectCounterValue);

    return (
        <div className='counter-container'>
            <span className='counter-value'>{currentCounterValue}</span>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Counter;
```

### counter.styles.scss

```css
.counter-container {
  height: 34px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fef0ef;
  border: 2px solid #ae5f5f;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.counter-value {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ae5f5f;
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

### single-card.component.jsx

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  selectCards,
  selectIsCardRotationDisabled,
} from '../../store/cards/cards.selector';
import { setCurrentImagePath } from '../../store/cards/cards.action';
import './single-card.styles.scss';

export const CARD_TYPE_CLASSES = {
  easy: 'easy',
  medium: 'medium',
  hard: 'hard',
};

const SingleCard = ({ card }) => {
  const { name, imagePath, currentImagePath } = card;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cards = useSelector(selectCards);
  const isCardRotationDisabled = useSelector(selectIsCardRotationDisabled);
  
  const toggleImagePath = () =>
    dispatch(setCurrentImagePath(cards, [card], imagePath));

  const currentImagePathHandler = () => {
    if (!isCardRotationDisabled) toggleImagePath();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <img
        className={`single-card-container ${
          currentImagePath === imagePath ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden'
        }`}
        src={currentImagePath}
        alt={`${name}`}
        onClick={currentImagePathHandler}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default SingleCard;
```

### single-card.styles.scss

```css
.single-card-container {
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.hidden {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.unhidden {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

### game-area.component.jsx

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setCards, setCurrentImagePath } from '../../store/cards/cards.action';
import { selectEmptyImagePath } from '../../store/cards/cards.selector';
import { selectGameDifficulty } from '../../store/game-difficulty/game-difficulty.selector';
import { setCounterValue } from '../../store/counter/counter.action';
import CardsDirectory from '../../components/cards-directory/cards-directory.component';
import Counter from '../../components/counter/counter.component';
import { CARD_TYPE_CLASSES } from '../../components/single-card/single-card.component';
import { CARDS_DATA } from '../../cards-data';
import Button, {
  BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES,
} from '../../components/button/button.component';
import './game-area.component.styles.scss';

const gameDifficulties = {
  easy: 6,
  medium: 8,
  hard: 10,
};

const GameArea = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const emptyImagePath = useSelector(selectEmptyImagePath);
  const gameDifficulty = useSelector(selectGameDifficulty);

  const getRandomCards = (cardsCount) =>
    CARDS_DATA.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
      .filter((card) => card.id !== 0)
      .slice(0, cardsCount);
  
  const getCopiedCards = (cardsToCopy) =>
    cardsToCopy.map((card) => ({
      ...card,
      id: card.id + 10,
    }));
  
  const getShuffledCards = (cards) =>
    cards.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  
  const getCardsCount = (gameDifficulty) =>
    gameDifficulties[gameDifficulty];
  
  const startNewGame = () => {
    const cardsCount = getCardsCount(gameDifficulty);
    const randomCards = getRandomCards(cardsCount);
    const copiedCards = getCopiedCards(randomCards);
    const cards = [...randomCards.concat(copiedCards)];
    const shuffledCards = getShuffledCards(cards);
    const initialCounterValue = 0;

    dispatch(setCards(shuffledCards));
    dispatch(setCurrentImagePath(cards, shuffledCards, emptyImagePath));
    dispatch(setCounterValue(initialCounterValue));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    startNewGame();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='game-area-container'>
      <CardsDirectory cardType={CARD_TYPE_CLASSES[gameDifficulty]} />
      <div className='bottom-panel'>
        <Button
          buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.restart}
          type='button'
          onClick={startNewGame}
        >
          Restart Game
        </Button>
        <Counter />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameArea;
```

### game-area.component.styles.scss

```css
.bottom-panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

### menu.component.jsx

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setGameDifficulty } from '../../store/game-difficulty/game-difficulty.action';
import Button, {
  BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES,
} from '../../components/button/button.component';
import './menu.styles.scss';

const Menu = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const goToGameAreaHandler = () => {
    navigate('/game-area');
  };
  const difficultyLevelHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const gameDifficulty = event.target.innerText.toLowerCase();
    dispatch(setGameDifficulty(gameDifficulty));
  };

  return (
    <div className='menu-container'>
      <h1>Memo Game</h1>
      <div className='difficulty-container'>
        <h2>Select difficulty:</h2>
        <Button
          buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.difficultyEasy}
          type='button'
          onClick={difficultyLevelHandler}
        >
          Easy
        </Button>
        <Button
          buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.difficultyMedium}
          type='button'
          onClick={difficultyLevelHandler}
        >
          Medium
        </Button>
        <Button
          buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.difficultyHard}
          type='button'
          onClick={difficultyLevelHandler}
        >
          Hard
        </Button>
      </div>
      <Button
        buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.start}
        type='button'
        onClick={goToGameAreaHandler}
      >
        Start Game
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

### menu.styles.scss

```css
.menu-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4%;
  border: 5px solid #dcabae;
  background-color: #ffdfdc;
  color: #4a586e;

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

.difficulty-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

### reducer.utils.js

```js
export const createAction = (type, payload) => ({ type, payload });
```

### root-reducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { cardsReducer } from './cards/cards.reducer';
import { gameDifficultyReducer } from './game-difficulty/game-difficulty.reducer';
import { counterReducer } from './counter/counter.reducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cards: cardsReducer,
    gameDifficulty: gameDifficultyReducer,
    counter: counterReducer
});
```

### store.js

```js
import { compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { rootReducer } from './root-reducer';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const middleWares = [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && logger].filter(
  Boolean
);

const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWares));

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  composedEnhancers
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

### cards.action.js

```js
import CARDS_ACTION_TYPES from './cards.types';
import { createAction } from '../reducer.utils';

const updateCurrentImagePath = (cards, cardsToUpdate, currentImagePath) => {
    return cards.map((card) => {
        const existingCard = cardsToUpdate.find(
            (cardToUpdate) => cardToUpdate.id == card.id
        );

        return existingCard !== undefined
            ? { ...card, currentImagePath: currentImagePath }
            : card;
    });
};

const updateIsCardDisabled = (cards, cardsToUpdate) => {
    return cards.map((card) => {
        const existingCard = cardsToUpdate.find(
            (cardToUpdate) => cardToUpdate.id == card.id
        );

        return existingCard !== undefined
            ? { ...card, isCardDisabled: true }
            : card;
    });
};

export const setCards = (cards) =>
    createAction(CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARDS, cards);

export const setCurrentImagePath = (cards, cardsToUpdate, currentImagePath) => {
    const newCards = updateCurrentImagePath(
        cards,
        cardsToUpdate,
        currentImagePath
    );
    return createAction(CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARDS, newCards);
};

export const setIsCardDisabled = (cards, cardsToUpdate) => {
    const newCards = updateIsCardDisabled(cards, cardsToUpdate);
    return createAction(CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARDS, newCards);
};

export const setIsRotationDisabled = (isRotationDisabled) =>
    createAction(
        CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_IS_CARD_ROTATION_DISABLED,
        isRotationDisabled
    );
```

### cards.reducer.js

```js
import { CARDS_DATA } from '../../cards-data';
import CARDS_ACTION_TYPES from './cards.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    cards: [],
    emptyImagePath: CARDS_DATA[0].imagePath,
    isCardRotationDisabled: false,
};

export const cardsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {}) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARDS:
            return {
                ...state,
                cards: payload,
            };
        case CARDS_ACTION_TYPES.SET_IS_CARD_ROTATION_DISABLED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isCardRotationDisabled: payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

### cards.selector.js

```js
export const selectCards = (state) =>
    state.cards.cards;

export const selectEmptyImagePath = (state) =>
    state.cards.emptyImagePath;

export const selectIsCardRotationDisabled = (state) =>
    state.cards.isCardRotationDisabled;
```

### cards.types.js

```js
const CARDS_ACTION_TYPES = {
    SET_CARDS: 'SET_CARDS',
    SET_IS_CARD_ROTATION_DISABLED: 'SET_IS_CARD_ROTATION_DISABLED'
};

export default CARDS_ACTION_TYPES;
```

### counter.action.js

```js
import { createAction } from "../reducer.utils"
import COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES from "./counter.types";

export const setCounterValue = (counterValue) =>
    createAction(COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES.SET_COUNTER_VALUE, counterValue);
```

### counter.reducer.js

```js
import COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES from './counter.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    counterValue: 0
};

export const counterReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {}) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES.SET_COUNTER_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                counterValue: payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    } 
};
```

### counter.selector.js

```js
export const selectCounterValue = (state) =>
    state.counter.counterValue;
```

### counter.types.js

```js
const COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES = {
    SET_COUNTER_VALUE: 'SET_COUNTER_VALUE'
};

export default COUNTER_ACTION_TYPES;
```

### game-difficulty.action.js

```js
import GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES from './game-difficulty.types';
import { createAction } from '../reducer.utils';

export const setGameDifficulty = (gameDifficulty) =>
    createAction(GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARD_COUNT, gameDifficulty);
```

### game-difficulty.reducer.js

```js
import GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES from './game-difficulty.types';

const INITIAL_GAME_DIFFICULTY_STATE = {
    difficulty: 'easy',
};

export const gameDifficultyReducer = (
    state = INITIAL_GAME_DIFFICULTY_STATE,
    action = {}
) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES.SET_CARD_COUNT:
            return {
                ...state,
                difficulty: payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

### game-difficulty.selector.js

```js
export const selectGameDifficulty = (state) =>
    state.gameDifficulty.difficulty;
```

### game-difficulty.types.js

```js
const GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES = {
    SET_CARD_COUNT: 'SET_CARD_COUNT'
};

export default GAME_DIFFICULTY_ACTION_TYPES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing great and this code is very clean and well-organized.  Keep up the good work!

The biggest area for improvement that I see is in the `cards.action.js` file.  **You have a lot of action creators which are doing work that belongs in the reducer.**  The action should describe what happened, which is that card 123 was disabled.  It's the job of the reducer to determine what to do about that, which is to update the array of cards so that the card you disabled has `isCardDisabled: true`.  This is discussed in more detail in the [Model Actions as Events, Not Setters](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters) section of the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/).

As a result of putting all the logic in your action creators, you're also having to pass way too much data to your actions.  An action to disable one or more individual cards should not need to know about all of the cards in the game.  You should only pass enough information to describe the event that happened.  That is: which card ids are effected, and whether you are enabling or disabling them.

These are examples of good actions:

```
dispatch(disableCard(123));
dispatch(disableCards([123, 124]));
dispatch(toggleCardsDisabled({ ids: [123, 124], isDisabled: false }));
```

I always recommend that people use [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) because it's such a great tool.  You're taking steps to make your Redux code clean and maintainable with your `reducer.utils.js` file and `createAction` utility.  If you follow down that path far enough then you'll eventually recreate Redux Toolkit.  But it's already been created and you can just use it!